# Pulling property up to Facade

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

I have a socket communication subsystem accessible by `SocketContext` facade, the only public class in class library. `SocketContext` allows you to connect to remote endpoind, send and receive messages.

The problem is following: let's say `SocketContext` consumer wants to monitor sent messages queue (send process is asynchronous).

Well, we need to add `int QueueSize {get;}` property in `SocketContext` but what happens next is we are going to find who is aware of queue size and it is a `DataSocket` class that `SocketContext` is not aware of, so to pull that property to `SocketContext` i have to wrap it multiple times like this:

```
// DataSocket -> Connection -> SocketClient -> SocketContext

internal class DataSocket
{ 
  public int QueueSize { get{ /* calculating and returning actual value */ }}
}

internal class Connection
{
   IDataSocket _dataSocket;
   int QueueSize { get{ return _dataSocket.QueueSize; }}
}

internal class SocketClient
{
   IConnection _connection;
   int QueueSize { get{ return _connection.QueueSize; }}
}

public class SocketContext
{
   ISocketClient _client;
   int QueueSize { get{ return _client.QueueSize; }}
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `SocketContext` facade, the only public class in class library.

I would say this could be one of the first problems. if there is only 1 public component then it makes it very difficult to expose functionality. This also fails concepts like single responsibility, open/closed design and interface segregation. you basically have 1 object doing everything.

There may be a single access point like the `SocketContextFacade`, but that is how you enter the API which can then expose other objects/components the client can interact with.

Alot of 3rd party libraries I use usually have 2 aspects to them.

1. Configuration
2. Runtime

Configuration happens once, at start up. It tells the library how to behave for your particular needs. The runtime is used throughout the system, behaving according to the configuration. Here are some examples:

1. Entity Framework/Nhibernate

   1. Configure - DB mappings
   2. Runtime - session/dbcontext
2. fluent validation

   1. Configuration - validation rules
   2. Runtime - validation engine and the results of validating an object
3. Service Buses

   1. Configuration - end point routing, queue management, error handling
   2. Runtime - message handlers

Comment: Well, i was thinking about EF when designing, my Context is meant to be like `DbContext`. 

Typical usage is: `var context = new SocketContext(ip, port);` `context.Subscribe(messageId,messageHandler);` `context.Send(message);'.

I don't see how making more public classes will help :(

Comment: just making it public won't help. but if it's public it can be exposed to the client. the `SocketContext` might expose `DataSocket` or `Connection` object itself, rather than the properties of the socket or connection.

Comment: Thing is - classes are in a chain of responsibility, only adjacent classes are aware of each other, if i make `IDataSocket _dataSocket;`  `IConnection _connection;` and `ISocketClient _client;` public it will be possible for consumer to access desired property like this `context.Client.Connection.DataSocket.QueueSize`
which is fine, i guess

Comment: ... but is it fine that all the intermediate classes now have access to each other, or am i being paranoid?

Comment: a chain of objects that deep still seems like a design problem to me. But there isn't much more that can be done given the limited amount of code. you may want to post your code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com to get more input on the overall design.